# puzzle about array initialize in C

Tags: c

I read piece of code like below:

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef unsigned char u8;
int main(){
  enum { RA, R1, R2, R3, PC };
  u8 R[] = {
    [RA] = 0, 
    [R1] = 0,
    [R2] = 0,
    [R3] = 0,
    [PC] = 0,
  };
  return 0;
}
```

From objdump, I know every element in R[] is set to zero:

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   c7 44 24 fb 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x5(%rsp)
   7:   00
   8:   c6 44 24 ff 00          movb   $0x0,-0x1(%rsp)
   d:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  12:   c3                      retq
```

However, I haven't seen this in the book I'm learning from. Could you explain the detail?

Comment: I hope not. It is unreadable. Please boys and girls do not program this way

Comment: You can read about "array designators" [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization). However, they are not commonly used.

Comment: Why are you using `typedef unsigned char u8;` right after `#include <stdint.h>`?  Just use the standard `uint8_t`.  (For the pedants:  Yes, `uint8_t` might not exist, but if it doesn't `u8` isn't likely to be 8 bits either...)

Comment: The values of enum fields start at `0` and increment by `1` for each successive step (if not specified otherwise). In your case, `RA` is `0`, `R1` is `1` ... `PC` is `4`

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted uses **designated initializers**. Although these are far more common when [initializing elements of structures or unions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization), such designators *can* also be used for [array elements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization).

In fact, [this Draft C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) gives an example that is very similar to the code you posted:

> ##### 6.7.9 Initialization
>
> …
> …
> 33 EXAMPLE 9  Arrays can be initialized to correspond to the elements of an enumeration by using designators:
>
> ```
> enum { member_one, member_two }; 
> const char *nm[] = {
>       [member_two] = "member two",
>       [member_one] = "member one",
> };
> ```

You can use such designators to initialize *specific* sub-objects of aggregate types (like structures and arrays). In the case of structures, those sub-objects will be the individual members; for arrays, they will be elements of the array.

A "non-designated" array initializer will set elements starting from index zero. Thus:

```c
int arr[4] = {1,2,};
```

will initialize the array elements to `1 2 0 0`. However, if you want to only *explicitly* initialize the second and third elements, then you can use a designator:

```c
int arr[4] = { [1] = 1, 2 };
```

Note that, after any given designator, subsequent (non-designated) initial values will be applied to subsequent elements, in order, so the above line will set the initial values of `arr` to `0 1 2 0`, respectively.

One can 'mix and mingle' designated and non-designated initialization:

```c
int arr[4] = { [1] = 1, [3] = 2 };
```

This will set the elements to `0 1 0 2`. In each of the above three examples, all elements *not* explicitly initialized will be *implicitly* initialized to the values they would have if they were declared as `static` (which will be zero for `int` data).

Comment: Thx for your great help !

Comment: Merely pointing to information elsewhere is not an adequate answer for Stack Overflow. An answer should explain what a designated initializer is and what it does. For example, it ought to state that `[i] = 3` initializes the array element with index `i` to the value 3. Even the quoted text that was included in the answer does not state this.

Comment: Fair point, @Eric. I've added some further explanation and examples that (hopefully) makes this a better answer.